# OpenVPN limit monthly transfer

Tags: linux, debian, openvpn

I want to limit clients with my OpenVPN to about 5gb/month,then autodisconect them until the next 1st.

Is there an easy way to do this with Openvpn?

Comment: Natively with OpenVPN? No.  Scripting it yourself or using a custom app?  It depends on how you have your OpenVPN set up.  If you have it as one service with multiple users, then you'll need to script something that keeps track of user and interface counter.  If you have multiple clients, but use the same username, then, you'll need a script to track mac addresses and interface counter.  If you have multiple site-to-site VPNs, then all you need is an interface counter.  As for taking the VPN down, you can script it to keep the VPN off or you can use a packet shaper to reduce outgoing bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

Roughly:

Cron job at the first of the month that resets the accumulated count to 0. A regular script (per minute?) that dumps the current interface counter, compares the last counter value, and adds that back to the current accumulated count. That part is necessary because the interface counter might be reset to 0 and you want an increasing count only.

Finally, your daemon script will have have a regularly running check something like:

```
if accumulated_data > 5*1024^3:
    ensure_vpn_down()
else:
    ensure_vpn_up()
```